# tinymce textarea cloning renders partial view inside htmleditor content

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I have a partial view with a couple of textboxes and a textarea for tinymce. In my main form I have this view as a hidden element:

```
<div id="template" style="display: none">
  <div id="lessonplan" style="display: none">
    <div id="lessonplanedit">
      LessonPlan
      <br />
      @Html.Partial("LessonPlanEdit", new LessonPlan())
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

On button click I am cloning this div:

```
function addlessonplan(component) {
    var idiv = $("#"+component).clone();// + component).clone(); //.html();

    idiv.removeAttr("style");

    var divid = component + '_' + counter++;
    var newid = component + '_' + counter++;
    idiv.attr("id", newid);

    $("#panel").append('<div id="' + divid + '"></div>');

    $("#" + divid).append(idiv);

    tinymceinit();
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, newid);
    tinyMCE.get(newid).setContent('');
}
```

I am getting the result as this:
[image]
 i.e. the partial view is rendered inside the htmleditor. Do you have any idea why this is happening?